Weird IP Address while GIT pull
Everything was working good until one day while trying to pull repository from Azure Dev Ops I'm getting below error:
exec-cmd.c:243          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Artur-Work/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
http.c:937              == Info: Couldn't find host dev.azure.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
http.c:937              == Info: Trying 10.95.163.194:8092...
http.c:937              == Info: connect to 10.95.163.194 port 8092 from 0.0.0.0 port 51891 failed: Timed out
http.c:937              == Info: Failed to connect to 10.95.163.194 port 8092 after 21065 ms: Could not connect to server
http.c:937              == Info: closing connection #0
fatal: unable to access 'https://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_git/xxxx/': Failed to connect to 10.95.163.194 port 8092 after 21065 ms: Could not connect to server

My question is from where that 10.95.163.194:8092 that is being picked ?? Is is stored somewhere? As this server has literaly nothing to do with Azure Dev Ops. On second computer git clone/push/pull works perfectly fine there is no trying to connect 10.95.163.194 port 8092, same internet connection.

Git is configured to use an HTTP proxy on your computer. There are various places where a proxy may have been configured, including:

the global git configuration on your computer
the local git repository

You can check this by running git config --show-origin http.proxy or by checking the .gitconfig files in your repisitory's .git directory or your home directory.
If this is defined, you can unset it with
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --unset http.proxy

depending on where exactly the setting was defined.
You may also have one or both of the HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY environment variables defined. If so, you may have to unset those.

Thanks a lot ! I tried in many places and always something was there but it is working :)
